# Text choices attribute not recognised

Tags: python, django, django-models, module, multi-select

I'm trying to create a model with `django-multiselectfield`, but when I run

`python manage.py runserver`

I get an error saying :

`AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'TextChoices'`.

I successfully installed `django-multiselectfield-0.1.10` and I can't figure out why I get this error. Thanks for any help!

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField


class MovieGenre(models.TextChoices):
        Action = 'Action'
        Horror = 'Horror'
        Comedy = 'Comedy'

 genre = MultiSelectField(
        choices=MovieGenre.choices,
        max_choices=3,
        min_choices=1
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Answer (score 4):

Which version of Django do you use?

**models.TextChoices** is new in Django 3.0

> New in Django 3.0: The TextChoices, IntegerChoices, and Choices
>   classes were added.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices

Your error has nothing to do with "django-multiselectfield-0.1.10"

You can also define your choices as:

```
MOVIE_GENGRE = (
    ('action', 'Action'),
    ('horror', 'Horror'),
    ('comedy', 'Comedy'),
)
```

Comment: Im using 2.1! Might be a problem! I will try to upgrade it to 3.0 ! Thanks !! :)))

Comment: Alright, now I upgrated it to Django 3.0 but I'm still getting an error saying : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiselectfield'

Comment: It may be that django-multiselectfield-0.1.10 does not support Django 3.0

Answer (score 0):

TextChoices work only in Django 3.x, try to update your packadge

```sh
pip3 install django==3.0
```

or later version